# Need some guidance with while expression

Tags: java, while-loop

So, I've been coding this hangman program and at the beginning,  I want the user to have to type "start" for the program to begin. So, here's what I have so far:

```
package hangman;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start;
        System.out.print("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("Type start to begin!");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        start = myScanner.nextInt();
        while (

        }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I got stuck on the while expression and don't know what to put.

I'm trying to make sure that what the user types equals the word "start". Also is using the `myScanner.next*Int*();` statement the right statement to use? (sorry if I'm using the wrong term)

Or do I have to replace `Int` with something else since it's a word? Also, on the `while` loop, I tried to compare what the user typed to the word "start" `(start = "start")`, but received an `incompatible operand types int and String` error message.
What I think I have to do is create a string for the word "start" and somehow put that in the expression?

If someone could just walk me through on how to make the `while` loop expression make sure that what the user typed is equal to the word "start" and if I have to change the `.nextInt();` statement I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Put your best effort at code into your question

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you meant there. Well, since I don't know what to put in the while expression, I've tried while (start == "start"), so that it would check to see if start, which is what the user typed equals the word "start", but I received the ""incompatible operand types int and String" " error. Also, I used myScanner.nextInt();, and I'm not sure if I have to use Int, since the word "start" isn't an integer, so do you know what I would have to use? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as you are expecting the `String` `"start"`, this variable's type must be `String`, not `int`:

```
int start;
```

should be

```
String start;
```

About the other question:

> Is using the `myScanner.next*Int*();` statement the right statement to use?

No. `next()` is the one to be used here - it will return the typed token as a `String`.

You put the `next()` in a `while` loop like this:

```
package hangman;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String start;
        System.out.print("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("Type start to begin!");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        start = myScanner.next();
        while (!"start".equals(start)) {
            System.out.println("You must type start to begin!");
            start = myScanner.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for typing start!");
    }
}
```

Basically this will keep on reading the token (`start = myScanner.next();`) while the typed value is not `"start"` (`while (!"start".equals(start)) {`).

Run the code and hopefully everything is clear.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and see how it goes. :)

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I accepted your answer as I think it was the best. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String start;
    System.out.print("Welcome to Hangman!");
    System.out.println("Type start to begin!");
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    start = myScanner.nextLine();
    if (start.equals("start")) {
        System.out.println("User said 'start'");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This isn't 'start' :-(");
    }
}
```

`int` means "integer", it's a number, what you want is a `String`. And thus, you shouldn't use `nextInt()`, but `nextLine()`.

`while ()` is a loop, if you just want to test an expression, you have to use `if ()`.

The compare method of `String` is `equals()`, and you have to use it to compare your string `start` (wich contains what the user typed) with the string literal `"start"`.

The `else`code block is here for when the user didn't type "start", but something else.

Comment: Thanks, and I like the emoticons! ;)